# Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource HELM Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**What I Did:**
I installed Helm with

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/helm/master/scripts/get | bash
helm init --history-max 200
```

**Getting an error:**

```
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /root/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
```

1. what does that error mean?
2. How should I install Helm and tiller?

Ubuntu version: 18.04
Kubernetes version: 1.16
Helm version:

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

**Update:**
I tried @shawndodo's answer but still tiller not installed

```
helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm'
--output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

**Update 2:**
`helm init --history-max 200` working in kubernetes version 1.15

Comment: Do you have your kubernetes config setup at `KUBECONFIG`

Comment: Helm [v2.15.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.15.0) is released, and `helm init` now installs a Tiller Deployment with apiVersion `apps/v1`, making it compatible with newer versions of Kubernetes.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I met the same problem, then I found this reply on [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374#issuecomment-533427268).

```
helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

It works for me. You can see the detail in this issue.

Comment: Didn't work for me as well. Creates the deployment / service but unable to scale replicaset.

Comment: You also need to create the 'tiller' service account and the 'clusterrolebinding' for that service account. The three commands would look like this:  

    > kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system
    > kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
    > helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, Helm is not working with the current version of Kubernetes (1.16.0) as we can see on the issue [#6374](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374)

For now, we can work around the incompatibility by selecting an older version of Kubernetes.

### Starting minikube with a previous Kubernetes version

To solve this issue, simply start the minikube setting the version using the  `--kubernetes-version` param ([Ref.](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/configuration/kubernetes/)):

```
minikube delete

minikube start --kubernetes-version=1.15.4
```

Try to reboot the Helm too with the following command:

```
helm init
```

After that, you will be able to use the Helm without problems.

Answer (score 2):

So tiller is the server side component that your helm client talks to (tiller is due to be removed in Helm 3 due to various security issues). When running `helm init` the helm client installs tiller on the cluster that your kubectl is currently setup to connect with (keep in mind that in order to install tiller you need admin access the cluster as tiller needs cluster-wide admin access) However there are many different strategies to work with tiller:

- tiller per namespace: This is when you install tiller in a single namespace and only give it access to that namespace (vastly more secure than giving it cluster wide admin), you can find an article on how to [here](https://medium.com/@amimahloof/how-to-setup-helm-and-tiller-with-rbac-and-namespaces-34bf27f7d3c3)
- tillerless: This is when you run tiller locally, you will need to export `HELM_HOST` to poiunt to this tiller and tiller will use the kube config configured at `KUBECONFIG` more information found [here](https://rimusz.net/tillerless-helm)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue - exactly the same configuration as initial question:
Ubuntu version: 18.04
Kubernetes version: 1.16

@shawndodo's answer didn't work for me. There were some issues with the tiller deployment and the tiller pod was not getting created at all!

I tried installing the from canary build as described in Helm docs - https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#from-canary-builds

```
helm init --canary-image --upgrade
```

This didn't work a couple days ago, but tried again (with newer canary build) and it worked today (20191005).

Whether I run into other issues now using canary build remains to be seen, but I got past the initialisation issue...

Comment: I downgraded my k8s to 1.15 so i cant verify this. If this works for others as well, I can mark this answer as accepted

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN I'm using k8s 1.15.0 and having  the same issue. It doesn't seem to be tied with a specific k8s version...

Answer (score 1):

I tried all suggestions about changing the api version manually to fix this issue, this got rid of the errors but things didnt work properly afterwards. so in my case I removed my latest minicube installation and installed an old one on my mac using the below command, change minikube-darwin-amd64 to minikube-linux-amd64 if needed :

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v1.3.0/minikube-darwin-amd64 \
  && sudo install minikube-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

This downgraded my kubernetes to v1.15.2 which helm currently supports.

Answer (score 1):

- kubectl version: v1.16.0
- helm version: v2.14.3

  ```
  minikube start --memory=16384 --cpus=4

  helm init --service-account tiller --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | sed 's@  replicas: 1@  replicas: 1\n  selector: {"matchLabels": {"app": "helm", "name": "tiller"}}@' | kubectl apply -f -

  helm template istio-1.3.3/install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init --name istio-init --namespace istio-system | kubectl apply -f - 

  helm template istio-1.3.3/install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system | kubectl apply -f -
  ```

Answer (score 0):

We need to have tiller installed in the cluster before we start using helm. `helm init` command installs tiller in the cluster and also we need to have RBAC configured in the cluster for tiller as well. [Here](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#role-based-access-control) you'll find out the RBAC rules required as per your need for your k8s cluster.

Comment: sir, I think you are not getting the question. @Tyto

Answer (score 0):

try

`apt-get upgrade helm` in my case it worked.

Comment: previously, it was a bug. I guess its fixed now @Karthik

Answer (score -2):

```
helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.