# `Error: could not find tiller` when running `helm version`

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, minikube

I have `minikube` and `kubectl` installed:

```
$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.4.0
commit: 7969c25a98a018b94ea87d949350f3271e9d64b6

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:27:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I have then followed the instructions from https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/:

1. I have downloaded https://get.helm.sh/helm-v2.13.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
2. I have run

```
$ tar -xzvf Downloads/helm-v2.13.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz linux-amd64/
linux-amd64/LICENSE
linux-amd64/tiller
linux-amd64/helm
linux-amd64/README.md
```

But now, if I check my `helm` version, I get this:

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

I have tried running `helm init`, but get the following:

```
$ helm init
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/SERILOCAL/<my-username>/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
```

How can I get `helm` to initialise correctly?

Comment: Is this not a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers"?

Comment: Either way, am very happy that I got an answer, despite the downvotes :)

Comment: Helm [v2.15.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.15.0) is released, and `helm init` now installs a Tiller Deployment with apiVersion `apps/v1`, making it compatible with newer versions of Kubernetes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The current helm version does not work with kubernetes version 1.16.0

You can downgrade kubernetes to version 1.15.3

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version 1.15.3
helm init
```

or use my solution to fix it at version 1.16.0

You have to create tiller [**Service Account**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) and [**ClusterRoleBinding**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding).

You can simply do that by using those commands:

```
kubectl --namespace kube-system create sa tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
```

And simply create tiller

```
helm init --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much! Was not expecting this, you helped me on something I was stuck on for more than I'm proud to admit

Comment: Thank you for this. Huge pain in the ass that I decided to upgrade just before midnight and ran into this =,=

Answer (score 2):

I met with the same problem, @shawndodo showed me this https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374#issuecomment-533427268

```
helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

you can try this one.
(Posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075103/error-error-installing-the-server-could-not-find-the-requested-resource-helm-k))