# Unable to deploy services using helm chart on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy service using helm chart on kubernetes cluster. It is throwing error as

> "Error: Non-absolute URLs should be in form of
>   repo_name/path_to_chart, got: guestbook"

Here is the guestbook service that i am deploying https://github.com/phcollignon/helm/tree/master/lab5_helm_chart_version1/

provider.helm v2.14.3

provider.kubernetes v1.16

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:27:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
$ helm install guestbook
Error: failed to download "guestbook" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

```
$ helm install guestbook --debug
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '39069'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:39069"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
Error: Non-absolute URLs should be in form of repo_name/path_to_chart, got: guestbook
```

Comment: As per error suggestion when you try to install the chart, have you tried to run `helm repo update`?

Comment: i did it, Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5):

There are five different ways you can express the chart you want to install:

1. By chart reference: `helm install stable/mariadb`
2. By path to a packaged chart: `helm install ./nginx-1.2.3.tgz`
3. By path to an unpacked chart directory: `helm install ./nginx`
4. By absolute URL: `helm install https://example.com/charts/nginx-1.2.3.tgz`
5. By chart reference and repo url: `helm install --repo https://example.com/charts/ nginx`

There is example using option number **3**

Download github repository using this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/phcollignon/helm
```

Then go to the **lab5_helm_chart_version1** file

```
cd helm/lab5_helm_chart_version1
```

And simply use helm install to create guestbook

```
helm install chart/guestbook/ --name guestbook
```

Comment: @VKR i am getting below error when in run as $ helm install guestbook/ --name guestbook
Error: release guestbook failed: namespaces "default" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Comment: Your default user doesn't have an access to resources in default namespace, look into documentation how to deal with rbac and how to grant user accesses

Comment: Provide step by step info how you instated helm

Comment: look at one of @jt97 answers - he already solved this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101218/9929015

Answer (score 0):

The issue is path where the chart is located should be specified.
In my case, the below command worked on the powershell terminal

> helm install demo-guestbook .\chart\guestbook\