# Can't do Helm Init : tiller not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install Traefik on a Ubuntu 18.10 master on my cluster using Helm.

I'm able to install Helm with snap `snap install helm --classic` but then when I want to install Tiller with the `helm init` command, I have the following output :

```
helm init                                                                                         
Creating /home/user/.helm                                                                                            
Creating /home/user/.helm/repository                                                                                 
Creating /home/user/.helm/repository/cache                                                                           
Creating /home/user/.helm/repository/local                                                                           
Creating /home/user/.helm/plugins                                                                                    
Creating /home/user/.helm/starters                                                                                   
Creating /home/user/.helm/cache/archive                                                                              
Creating /home/user/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml                                                               
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com                                            
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts                                                                 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/user/.helm.                                                                  
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
```

I've tried to install helm through the binaries from the official GitHub, it ends with the same error.

I've also tried to install Tiller manually by running :

`helm init --dry-run --debug >> tiller.yml`

But when I do `kubectl apply -f tiller.yml`, it says that it couldn't find extensions/v1beta1.

I'm running out of solutions so I'm asking for your help if you have any ideas !

```
---                                                                                                                      
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1                                                                                           
kind: Deployment                                                                                                         
metadata:                                                                                                                
  creationTimestamp: null                                                                                                
  labels:                                                                                                                
    app: helm                                                                                                            
    name: tiller                                                                                                         
  name: tiller-deploy                                                                                                    
  namespace: kube-system  
spec:                                                                                                                    
  replicas: 1                                                                                                            
  strategy: {}                                                                                                           
  template:                                                                                                              
    metadata:                                                                                                            
      creationTimestamp: null                                                                                            
      labels:                                                                                                            
        app: helm                                                                                                        
        name: tiller                                                                                                     
    spec:                                                                                                                
      automountServiceAccountToken: true                                                                                 
      containers:                                                                                                        
      - env:                                                                                                             
        - name: TILLER_NAMESPACE                                                                                         
          value: kube-system                                                                                             
        - name: TILLER_HISTORY_MAX                                                                                       
          value: "0"                                                                                                     
        image: gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.14.3                                                                     
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent                                                                                    
        livenessProbe:                                                                                                   
          httpGet:
          httpGet:                                                                                                       
            path: /liveness                                                                                              
            port: 44135                                                                                                  
          initialDelaySeconds: 1                                                                                         
          timeoutSeconds: 1                                                                                              
        name: tiller                                                                                                     
        ports:                                                                                                           
        - containerPort: 44134                                                                                           
          name: tiller                                                                                                   
        - containerPort: 44135                                                                                           
          name: http                                                                                                     
        readinessProbe:                                                                                                  
          httpGet:                                                                                                       
            path: /readiness                                                                                             
            port: 44135                                                                                                  
          initialDelaySeconds: 1                                                                                         
          timeoutSeconds: 1                                                                                              
        resources: {}                                                                                                    
status: {}

---                                                                                                                      
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                           
kind: Service                                                                                                            
metadata:                                                                                                                
  creationTimestamp: null                                                                                                
  labels:                                                                                                                
    app: helm                                                                                                            
    name: tiller                                                                                                         
  name: tiller-deploy                                                                                                    
  namespace: kube-system                                                                                                 
spec:                                                                                                                    
  ports:                                                                                                                 
  - name: tiller                                                                                                         
    port: 44134                                                                                                          
    targetPort: tiller                                                                                                   
  selector:                                                                                                              
    app: helm                                                                                                            
    name: tiller                                                                                                         
  type: ClusterIP                                                                                                        
status:                                                                                                                  
  loadBalancer: {}                                                                                                       

...
```

Comment: What is your k8s version 1.16?

Comment: If it is k8s version 1.16, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101218/11977760) is link to my answer in another question with the same error.

Comment: My k8s version is 1.16, I didn't know there were issues with this version, thanks for the help I'll try to downgrade !

Comment: I didn't have to downgrade, your workaround worked like a charm ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: Helm [v2.15.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.15.0) is released, and `helm init` now installs a Tiller Deployment with apiVersion `apps/v1`, making it compatible with newer versions of Kubernetes.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello Great news ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Workaround, using command:

> helm init --service-account tiller --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion:
>   extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | sed 's@  replicas: 1@ 
>   replicas: 1\n  selector: {"matchLabels": {"app": "helm", "name":
>   "tiller"}}@' | kubectl apply -f -

If k8s version is : 1.16, you should downgrade to 1.14.

Comment: What about RBAC for tiller?

Comment: My k8s version is 1.16, I didn't know there were issues with this version, thanks for the help I'll try to downgrade !

Answer (score 0):

> If it is k8s version 1.16, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101218/11977760) is link to my answer in another
>   question with the same error. – jt97

The comment of jt97 was the perfect workaround, thanks !