# Getting helm status failed for prometheus-9.5.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, hyper-v

I am following but not able to understand and troubleshoot why deployment status is failed.   https://linuxacademy.com/cp/courses/lesson/course/2205/lesson/2/module/218

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/helm/master/scripts/get > /tmp/get_helm.sh
chmod 700 /tmp/get_helm.sh
DESIRED_VERSION=v2.8.2 /tmp/get_helm.sh
helm init --wait
kubectl --namespace=kube-system create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
helm ls
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/charts
cd charts
git checkout efdcffe0b6973111ec6e5e83136ea74cdbe6527d
cd ../
vi prometheus-values.yml
prometheus-values.yml:

alertmanager:
    persistentVolume:
        enabled: false
server:
    persistentVolume:
        enabled: false
Then run:

helm install -f prometheus-values.yml charts/stable/prometheus --name prometheus --namespace prometheus
vi grafana-values.yml
grafana-values.yml:

adminPassword: password
Then run:

helm install -f grafana-values.yml charts/stable/grafana/ --name grafana --namespace grafana
vi grafana-ext.yml
grafana-ext.yml:

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  namespace: grafana
  name: grafana-ext
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: grafana
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    nodePort: 8080
Then run:

kubectl apply -f grafana-ext.yml
You can check on the status of the prometheus and grafana pods with these commands:

kubectl get pods -n prometheus
kubectl get pods -n grafana
When setting up your dastasource in grafana, use this url:

http://prometheus-server.prometheus.svc.cluster.local
```

having an issue for the same in 2 different environment

1. k8s cluster running in aws got Status Failed

   $ kubectl describe deploy prometheus -n prometheus

> Error from server  (NotFound): deployments.extensions "prometheus" not
>   found

$ helm ls --all

```
   NAME            REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                   NAMESPACE
grafana         1               Tue Dec 17 12:26:32 2019        DEPLOYED        grafana-1.8.0           grafana
prometheus      1               Wed Dec 18 10:24:58 2019        FAILED          prometheus-9.5.4        prometheus
```

2. k8s cluster running on hyper V

   admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog$ helm init --wait

   > ```
   >     $HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/admin1/.helm.
   >     Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
   > ```

admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/.helm$ kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
poc-k8s-master   Ready    master   24d   v1.16.3   192.168.137.2   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-62-generic   docker://19.3.5
poc-k8s-node1    Ready    <none>   24d   v1.16.3   192.168.137.3   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-62-generic   docker://18.6.2
```

admin@ip-172-20-49-150:~/dev-migration/stage$ helm install stable/prometheus

```
Error: release loping-owl failed: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "loping-owl-prometheus-kube-state-metrics" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{Resources:["namespaces"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["namespaces"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["nodes"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["nodes"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["persistentvolumeclaims"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["persistentvolumeclaims"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["resourcequotas"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["resourcequotas"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["replicationcontrollers"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["replicationcontrollers"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["limitranges"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["limitranges"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["persistentvolumeclaims"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["persistentvolumeclaims"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["persistentvolumes"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["persistentvolumes"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["configmaps"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["configmaps"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["daemonsets"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["daemonsets"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["deployments"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["deployments"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["replicasets"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["replicasets"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["daemonsets"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["daemonsets"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["daemonsets"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["deployments"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["deployments"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["deployments"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["statefulsets"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["statefulsets"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["statefulsets"], APIGroups:["apps"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["cronjobs"], APIGroups:["batch"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["cronjobs"], APIGroups:["batch"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["jobs"], APIGroups:["batch"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["jobs"], APIGroups:["batch"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["horizontalpodautoscalers"], APIGroups:["autoscaling"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["horizontalpodautoscalers"], APIGroups:["autoscaling"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["poddisruptionbudgets"], APIGroups:["policy"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["poddisruptionbudgets"], APIGroups:["policy"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["certificatesigningrequests"], APIGroups:["certificates.k8s.io"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["certificatesigningrequests"], APIGroups:["certificates.k8s.io"], Verbs:["watch"]}] user=&{system:serviceaccount:kube-system:tiller b474eab9-b753-11e9-83a0-06e8a114eea2 [system:serviceaccounts system:serviceaccounts:kube-system system:authenticated] map[]} ownerrules=[] ruleResolutionErrors=[[clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" not found]]
```

> admin@ip-172-20-49-150:~/dev-migration/stage$ kubectl
>   --namespace=kube-system create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default

```
   Error from server (AlreadyExists): clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "add-on-cluster-admin" already exists
```

admin@ip-172-20-49-150:~/dev-migration/stage$ helm inspect prometheus

```
Error: failed to download "prometheus"
```

Comment: any slight hint what failed status for prometheus

Comment: Please take a look on this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096041/error-could-not-find-tiller-when-running-helm-version). I think it will answer your second question.

Comment: @DawidKruk thanks for 2nd question any hint for 1st question coz I am not even able to kubectl describe the failed deployment

Comment: Try to first  fetch the chart and edit the values in `values.yaml` file in the chart and then install it. Commands: `helm fetch charts/stable/prometheus --untar` to download it. `helm install ./prometheus ` to install it.

Comment: @DawidKruk  admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog$ helm install -f prometheus-values.yml charts/stable/prometheus --name prometheus --namespace prometheus
Error: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/version: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

Comment: Is your Helm working properly? I think there is an issue with your outdated software versions. This helm version was commited on Mar 9, 2018.

Comment: @DawidKruk I tried DESIRED_VERSION=v2.8.2 /tmp/get_helm.sh ....and.....
DESIRED_VERSION=v2.13.1 /tmp/get_helm.sh
Helm v2.13.1 is available. Changing from version v2.8.2.
Downloading https://get.helm.sh/helm-v2.13.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
Preparing to install helm and tiller into /usr/local/bin
helm installed into /usr/local/bin/helm
tiller installed into /usr/local/bin/tiller
Run 'helm init' to configure helm.
admin@ip-172-20-49-150:~$ helm init
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/admin/.helm.
but still no use please can you let me know the version I should try...Thanks in Advance

Comment: I tried on helm and tiller version 2.14.1. Created a file with values like yours and run the `helm install -f prometheus-values.yaml stable/prometheus`. It deployed successfully. I would encourage you to try with version 2.14.1.