# Helm not initializing

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to initialize the helm chart using "**helm init**" command and also with "**helm init --wait**". But when I am running the command , I am only getting the message that,

```
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/docker/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
```

Result of "helm version" command is like following,

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", 
GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

**Updates On Running Commands for Trubleshooting**

**kubectl -n kube-system get pods**

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-6c9c86c88b-5wngt   1/1     Running   0          42h
calico-node-cvbdb                          1/1     Running   1          42h
calico-node-rpt9v                          1/1     Running   0          42h
coredns-58687784f9-nnq6g                   1/1     Running   5          42h
coredns-58687784f9-sc6p5                   1/1     Running   8          42h
dns-autoscaler-79599df498-wv7cp            1/1     Running   0          42h
kube-apiserver-mildevkub030                1/1     Running   0          42h
kube-controller-manager-mildevkub030       1/1     Running   3          42h
kube-proxy-wb7gp                           1/1     Running   0          42h
kube-proxy-xll9c                           1/1     Running   0          42h
kube-scheduler-mildevkub030                1/1     Running   0          42h
kubernetes-dashboard-556b9ff8f8-6kls9      1/1     Running   0          42h
nginx-proxy-mildevkub040                   1/1     Running   0          42h
nodelocaldns-kfrlm                         1/1     Running   0          42h
nodelocaldns-tvclh                         1/1     Running   0          42h
tiller-deploy-77855d9dcf-l4l85             1/1     Running   0          100m
```

**kubectl -n kube-system get deployments**

```
NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           42h
coredns                   2/2     2            2           42h
dns-autoscaler            1/1     1            1           42h
kubernetes-dashboard      1/1     1            1           42h
tiller-deploy             1/1     1            1           21h
```

**kubectl -n kube-system describe deployment tiller-deploy**

```
Name:                   tiller-deploy
Namespace:              kube-system
CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:43:17 -0400
Labels:                 app=helm
                    name=tiller
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:

{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations": 
{},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app":"helm","name":"tiller"},...
Selector:               app=helm,name=tiller
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 
unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=helm
                name=tiller
  Service Account:  tiller
Containers:
tiller:
 Image:       gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.14.3
 Ports:       44134/TCP, 44135/TCP
 Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
 Liveness:    http-get http://:44135/liveness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:   http-get http://:44135/readiness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
  Environment:
   TILLER_NAMESPACE:    kube-system
   TILLER_HISTORY_MAX:  0
 Mounts:                <none>
Volumes:                 <none>
Conditions:
 Type           Status  Reason
 ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
 OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   tiller-deploy-77855d9dcf (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: If you are using k8s 1.16.x, `helm init` is broken ([#6374](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374)) due to deprecation of some `beta` APIs. This question was already made, and a workaround can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58079963/7641078)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource HELM Kubenetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075103/error-error-installing-the-server-could-not-find-the-requested-resource-helm-k)

Comment: @EduardoBaitello -  I was already tried that , still getting the same error when I am checking the version. What I can do here ?

Comment: Helm [v2.15.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.15.0) is released, and `helm init` now installs a Tiller Deployment with apiVersion `apps/v1`, making it compatible with newer versions of Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Reset helm:

```
helm reset --force
```

2. Create service account for RBAC enabled cluster.

   In `rbac-config.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

```sh
$ kubectl create -f rbac-config.yaml
serviceaccount "tiller" created
clusterrolebinding "tiller" created
```

3. Initialize helm:

Try the first command, if it doesn't work, try 2nd one.

```
$ helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 200
```

```
$ helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: I was wrongly added in question. Both "helm init" and "helm init --wait" also tried. Error is like same. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Jacob I've edited my answer. Take a look, hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried sir. Both of command not working.After running second command I am getting the message -"deployment.apps/tiller-deploy configured
service/tiller-deploy configured". And when I am checking the helm version "Error: could not find tiller" message I am getting.

Comment: @Jacob, `helm reset --force` use this command, and repeat the process one more time.

Comment: If that doesn't work, attach the result of the following command to the question body: `kubectl -n kube-system get pods` `kubectl -n kube-system get deployments`  `kubectl -n kube-system describe deployment tiller-deploy`

Comment: Yes sir, I updated with those commands result. Can you please look on that? . And when I am running now the command "helm version" , it giving the client and server version properly. But when I tried this earlier , then it was getting only could not find tiller. And till this time i did not make any command run.How it is happening? I did not understood. Is this because of network issue or my calico issue that I am using?

Comment: @Jacob, It seems you're ready to go with helm :D Still facing any problem?